# How to route subcategories and pages in categories?

Tags: cakephp, routes, cakephp-3.0

My subcategories and pages in categories have similar structure. For example:
site.com/cat/page
site.com/cat/subcat
How can I route them? URLs consist only of strings, no IDs and any numbers.

Comment: your question is too general. Please provide some more specific tags. What CMS are you using? What's your stack?

Comment: I am using cakePHP 3

Comment: Sorry but your question is unclear. Do you get any error? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty straightforward, your routes.php could look like:

```
$routes->connect(
    '/cat/:page',
    ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'view'],
    ['page' => '\s+', 'pass' => ['page']]
);

$routes->connect(
    '/cat/:subcat/:page',
    ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'subcatView'],
    ['subcat' => '\s+', 'page' => '\s+', 'pass' => ['subcat', 'page']]
);
```

Next, in  your PagesController.php (actually you can use any other your controller/action, just substitute your names in routes above):

```
public function view($page) {
//i.e. if url is /cat/about then $page === 'about'
}
public function subcatView($subcat, $page) {
// i.e. if url is /cat/subcat/some_page then $subcat === 'subcat' & $page === 'some_page'
}
```

I highly recommend to refer [cakephp3 documentation, routes section](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#passing-parameters-to-action), it's clear enough to help you implement any magic.